# Scrapy and Webkit keeps freezing

Tags: python-2.7, webkit, scrapy

I am using scrapy to crawl some websites with JavaScript. The scraper works fine, but it keeps freezing at random places. I need to kill the script with ctrl+z, but it only freezes when i use this **downloader middleware:**

```
 from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest, HtmlResponse

    import gtk
    import webkit
    import jswebkit

    class WebkitDownloader( object ):
        def process_request( self, request, spider ):
            if( type(request) is not FormRequest ):
                webview = webkit.WebView()
                webview.connect( 'load-finished', lambda v,f: gtk.main_quit() )
                webview.load_uri( request.url )
                gtk.main()
                js = jswebkit.JSContext( webview.get_main_frame().get_global_context() )
                renderedBody = str( js.EvaluateScript( 'document.documentElement.innerHTML' ) )
                return HtmlResponse( request.url, body=renderedBody )
```

I tried debugging the script by printing every single step of the middleware, but it runs fine. It freezes when i see this in the terminal:

```
Message: console message: http://www.myurl.com/js/Shop.min.js?twsv=20140521122711 @642: JQMIGRATE: Logging is active
```

I tried different middlewares and download handlers, but it always freezes. I also checked my connection, but i cant see any patterns or signs of interruption. I am using the latest version of scrapy.

**2014-04-25 - Update**

When i do get it to run a couple of minutes, i get this error: 
Creating pipes for GWakeup: Too many open files

```
GLib-ERROR **: Creating pipes for GWakeup: Too many open files
```

**2014-05-27 - Update**

I ran "print" through every line of code in my middleware. It turns out it freezes the code and terminal randomly when it comes to the gtk.main() part. When I use the lsof command during a "freeze" i can see a bunch of "scrapy" "files" open. After a freeze my code wont run again until i reset my computer. I guess there is some kind of bug that causes a leakage.

Comment: I don't know the solution to your gtk problem but if you would like I have some code that solves this javascript problem.

Comment: Hi, so the WebkitDownloader solution was flawed from the beginning. Use splash together with Scrapy instead.

Comment: Please, consider making a proper response out of your solution, simple as it may be :)